# What are the limits of Python?

Tags: c++, python

I spent a few days reading about C++ and Python and I found that Python is so much simpler and easy to learn.

So I wonder does it really worth spending time learning it? Or should I invest that time learning C++ instead?

What can C++ do and Python can't ?

Comment: Both languages are Turing-complete -- they can do the same things.  Please edit your question to remove the "What can C++ do and python can't ?"  That's not a sensible thing to ask.

Comment: With C++ you can shoot in your foot and blow the whole leg off.

Comment: I disagree @S.Lott. The fact that they can both offer the same algorythm doesn't mean they can do the same thing. C++ can solve this problem with this algo in less than 3 seconds can be an exemple. Python can let you write this algo in less than 1 minute is another one.

Comment: @e-satis: Performance (and memory and other metrics related to the implementation) have nothing to do with "What can C++ do and Python can't ?".  Those are just measurements of the implementation, not features of the language.

Comment: Execution time and implementation speed are features.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Some Python limits :

**- Python is slow.** It can be improved in many ways (see other answers) but the bare bone cPython is 100 times slower that C/C++.

*This problem is getter more and more mitigated. With Numpy, Pypy and asyncio, most performance problems are not covered, and only very specific use cases are a bottleneck in Python anymore.*

**- Python is opened to anything.** It's really hard to protect / obfuscate / limit Python code.

**- Python is not hype.** Unlike Ruby, there is no "cool wave" around Python, and it's still much harder to find a experienced Python coder, than, let's say, a Java or a PHP pro.

**- After using Python, a lot of languages seems to be a pain to use.** You'd think it's good, but believe me, not always. When you have to go Javascript after a Python project, your eyes are in tears for at least 3 days. Really hard to get started.

**- It's harder to find web hosting than for popular solutions**, such as PHP.

<strike>**- As a dynamic language, you don't have the very handy refactoring tools** you could get with Java and Eclipse or C# and VS.</strike>

<strike>**- For the same reason, you can't rely on type checking as a safety net.** This is why pythonistas tend to follow best practice and write unit tests more often than others.</strike>

<strike>**- It seems I just can't find an IDE with a decent code completion**. PyDev, Gedit, Komodo, SPE, etc. just don't do it as good as it could be.</strike>

*With Python 3 types hints and tools like PyCharm or Sublime Text+Anaconda, the situation has changed a lot.*

**- The best docs are still in English only.** Some people don't deal well with it.

**- You have to get use to the syntax.** Not only you get spaces and line breaks instead of bracets, but you can forget about long lambdas, --i, and ternary operation.

Now, to me, these are not reasons to not learn a tool that will make you produce more while having more fun. But maybe it's just me :-)

Honestly, given that :

- C++ much harder to learn;
- You can do pretty much any thing you want with Python;
- You will get quicker result with Python in your projects.

Unless you have professional issues involving C++, you'd better learn Python first, it's more motivating. You still can learn C++ later, it's a useful language for system programming, embedded devices and such.

Don't try to learn both at the same times, multitasking rarely ends well.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question that was asked.

Comment: So is it bad that I like Python AND JavaScript?

Comment: I like Javascript too, but much like very spicy food, I need time to get back to it without crying.

Comment: thanks for Ulipad, I just new that, I was using PyScripter before.

Comment: Python is hyped. Ruby is not hyped. Ruby on rails is. Take rails away, who uses ruby ?

Comment: http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=fr_FR&word1=python&word2=ruby

Comment: +1 for answering from a less python-centric viewpoint. I never thought of re-factoring tools, because I don't use them myself.

Comment: [Pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is a very good ide if you can manage to buy it.

Comment: Now I'm just using sublime text. 10 years of Python IDE testing, and I end up using a proprietary software. But it's soooo good.

Comment: What does "cPython is 100 slower that C/C++" mean? 100 what?

Answer (score 32):

Here's why it's worth learning Python:

A comparatively small number of problems are constrained by the speed of the algorithm.  A comparatively large number of problems are bounded by the speed of the developer.

Comment: Sorry, late to the party but, uh, yes!

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you ask the converse question? Unlike C++, Python can give you [antigravity](http://xkcd.com/353/) and summon [souls](http://xkcd.com/413/) via its `import` command. On the other hand, C++'s 'equivalent' -- `#include` -- only allows you to get some boring I/O and math libraries.

Seriously though.. C++ allows you to do more low-level stuff e.g. kernel programming, and allows you to write programs that run much faster (*approximately* ~20x). <strike>You can use it to create real threads that can take advantage of multiple-cored processors, while Python ([due to its design](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/01/python-threads-and-the-global-interpreter-lock/)) can generally only run its simulated threads on a single core.</strike>

IMHO you should learn both; Python for web development and quick-and-dirty scripts, C++ to write systems code, desktop applications, as well as to have a better low-level understanding of the computer. If you're just starting out, then Python; it's much easier to begin with.

More concrete measurements on the speed difference can be found [here.](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=python3&lang2=gpp&box=1)

**Edit:** Seems like my information on multi-threading is out of date; see John Paulett's  comment.

Comment: With the new multiprocessing module the single-core caveat is no longer true.  Additionally, other implementations like Jython and Ironpython do not suffer from the GIL like CPython does.

Comment: Also, in terms of speed, I've had great luck using Pysco and Cython to dramatically speed up Python.  Pysco JITs the code and is a quick way to get a 4-100x improvement (although it is only 32-bit, since the developers are now working on PyPy). Cython will actually transform most Python code into C code, which you can them compile with gcc using its optimizations (-O3). In piece of code I had nearly a 1000x speed up.  Python also has great binding tools so that if you write your application in Python and discover a slow spot, you can rewrite that code as C and use SWIG or ctypes to call it.

Answer (score 4):

They're not used for the same kinds of things, in general.  Python is very useful for prototyping since it is so simple, but isn't always the best choice when speed is an important factor, since it is an interpreted language.  C++ can be heavily optimized, but as you said might be much more difficult to write and understand.

If you want to do systems or applications programming, you should learn C++.  If you are programming for fun and leisure, or to solve problems like at http://projecteuler.net/ then Python is a good choice too.

I personally also recommend learning C/C++ first if you want to get very serious about programming, because it teaches you the important concept of memory management, which might be overlooked in managed languages.

Comment: And definitely learn simple C before the crazy mess that is C++!

Answer (score 3):

if you are trying to find out whether you are still going to be employed some
time later using C++ or Python, don't concern yourself with a single language's longevity.
Learn to program.  Don't learn to program in `<insert a language here>.`

Here is an analogy: If your car is running fine (gets you where you're
going, has good mileage, cheap to maintain, relatively safe), there is
no logical reason to trade it in for another one.  None.  Whatsoever.
Drive it to the ground before you even consider what make or model to
get next.  But if you are already looking around thinking what car to
get, just go get it, stop asking everybody you know whether you should
do it.  If you need to ask, you need to change it.  It's as simple as
that.

Comment: We only have a limited time on Earth to study and learn, and one must be career-minded. If I could spend X hours now learning C, or X hours now learning *insert hip technology sure to pull $$$ jobs for 5 years*, I'll choose the latter, because it looks good on the resume and people like hiring people with prior experience.

Sure, you should always use the best tool for the job, but if you're stuck driving a beat-up hatchback when a corvette is available, you're just not clever.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall: I am not a _professional_ programmer (I hope I will become one, because I am _passionate_ about programming), but I would like to say that your opinion apalles me. I mean, learning a technology simply because it _looks good on the résumé_? And, pray tell, what makes you think, that C doesn't "look good" on the résumé?

Comment: What looks fine on a resume depends on where you want your career to go. For a web developer career, listing C probably isn't going to help you land a job (not that it will detract either, unless that's all you know).

Given limited available learning time, you're better off learning skills in demand than unmarketable ones.

Comment: From the TIOBE index, C and C++ are two of the top four languages.  So, they enjoy considerable popularity.  But little "sex-appeeal".

Answer (score 1):

From what I've been told, 1% of learning C++ is learning C. 1% is learning the extra basic features. 98% is learning to use the features in a safe, maintainable way, and coping with the dark hairy corners of the language.

Learning python will teach you to write code that is safe, and maintainable. I think that if you learn python then go back to C++, then you will be able to write good C++ code. Of course, that won't mean you will understand bad C++, or C++ code that was written in a non-pythonic way.

Limits to python?

- It's interpreted, so you have to ship the source and the interpreter; and processes will take much longer to start up.
- It's not C++, so it won't play with existing C++ code.
- It's a bit slower (even if you wrap the hot loops in C).*
- It encourages you to be "pythonic", and some problems are easier if you are not "pythonic".

*Python might be faster:

- Automatic GC. C++ is only faster if it doesn't leak too much.
- Dictionaries. Lots of code runs in O(N plus a bit), rather than O(N^2) if you use a dictionary. Sure, you can use a hash table in C++, but not everbody does.
- Memory management - the python interpreter caches some of the basic data structures' memory, then reallocates them, rather than hitting the system for new memory. This reduces system calls, which is  a very good thing.
- Profiling new algorithms is waaaay easier on python. In lots of problems, a better algorithm is more important than a linear speedup (which is what C++ gives you).
- If you are making a program that "only runs once" (scientific analysis, data migration, etc), then the compile-build-test cycle should be faster in python. That's what really counts ;)

Comment: The reference to "O(N plus a bit)" vs. "O(N^2)" is misguided.  (The gist is reasonably well intended but mis-use of big-O (computational order of complexity) expressions will undermine your credibility.

Operations on dictionary (hash tables) are O(1) (near constant time).  Searches through arrays (simpler to implement in C programs, for example) are O(n) (linear) time.  Binary searches are O(log(n)) (logarithmic) time.  Matrix operations are frequently O(n**2) (quadratic) time and things like qsort of O(n*log(n)).  Study that list and use them correctly to maximize your credibility.

Comment: I know that. But the code that often matters is things like "for all nodes, find the duplicates". That is O(N plus a bit) if you use dictionaries, and O(N^2) if you use a list. The "plus a bit" is because dictionaries get a smaller packing ratio when they get bigger (thus a few more collisions). Sorry, I didn't explain that too well.

Comment: You don't have to ship the interpreter - just tell the user where to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Learn a statically typed language and a scripting language. 
You can do whatever you want in either language. A well-written C++ code base is easier to maintain/debug than a Python code base written with the same level of competency.

If your goal is to do web stuff or scripting, Python is for you. Anything more advanced will require C++.

That being said, go for Python.

Comment: You can write more advanced applications in Python. Mercurial, BitTorrent, and Gentoo's Portage are just a few more complex apps written in Python.

Comment: you CAN write more complicated applications in Python. http://www.python.org/about/success/ But given a choice, you probably wouldn't

Comment: I disagree about the large project issue. I'm not certain that either one is easier, but from all my reading on this issue, neither is anyone else. There are plenty of concrete reasons to choose Python over C++ (or vice versa), but maintenance/debug being easier in C++, as far as I can tell, a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested: learn Python to study algorithms and higher level concepts and use it for prototyping and for places where you can.  Learn C/C++ and/or Java for the job market and for cases where you must use it.

Python's vastly easier syntax and high level libraries allow you to focus on interfaces and abstractions while still having a functional prototype.

Answer (score 0):

One significant difference not so far mentioned is the difference between a language like C++ that builds to native code, and a language like Python which by default puts a VM between you and the hardware.  For doing low-level work, like coding against the OS kernel, the native language will be the preferred option.

In practise, though, when you're working in that context it usually means dropping all the way down C (in its role as portable assembler) rather than being able to use C++ (and its runtime libraries), for much if not all of the code.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that people often use C for, and never (to my knowledge) Python, is low-level code such as operating-system kernels and embedded software.

C has a lot of of constructs that make it very easy to, for example, convert an arbitrary machine address into a pointer and dereference it, or tell the compiler that an address used for memory-mapped I/O might change even though this program doesn’t change it, or to specify the exact layout of an object in memory.  It’s designed to run as fast as possible, with as little wasted memory, rather than be safe.

That’s what the comments about “letting you shoot yourself in the foot” are mostly referring to.

Answer (score -1):

**Comparing Python with Java, Perl and other Programming Languages**

Prof. Lutz Prechelt from the University of Karlsruhe compared Python with other programming languages. He summarises his results: "80 implementations of the same set of requirements are compared for several properties, such as run time, memory consumption, source text length, comment density, program structure, reliability, and the amount of effort required for writing them. The results indicate that, for the given programming problem, which regards string manipulation and search in a dictionary, 'scripting languages' (Perl, Python, Rexx, Tcl) are ***more productive*** than 'conventional languages' (C, C++, Java). In terms of run time and memory consumption, they often turn out better than Java and not much worse than C or C++. In general, the differences between languages tend to be smaller than the typical differences due to different programmers within the same language. (see Lutz Prechelt, An empirical comparison of C, C++, Java, Perl, Python, Rexx, and Tcl, IEEE Computer, Vol. 30, (10), p. 23-29, Oct 2000.)

[source link](https://www.python-course.eu/why_python.php)