# I get this message when running my python in cmd "Indentation error expected an indented block expected"

Tags: python

```
import random
import time
name=input("Welcome to the game what is your name")

print(("This is a numbers game"),(name),
("You will be playing against the computer"))
print

("The idea of the game is to get closer than the computer to 21 without 
going over 21")
,ready="N"
ready = input("Are you ready to play the game?").lower
if ready == "yes" or ready =="y":
score=0
```

The Error is coming up and saying its the line above this
    while(score)<21 and(ready=="Y" or ready == "Yes" 
    or ready =="YES" or ready ==

```
"yes" or ready =="y"):
player1=random.randint(1,21)
score=(score+player1)

time.sleep(3)
print(("You have scored"),(score))
if score<21:
ready=input("Do you want to add more to your score")
if score>21:
print("Sorry Over 21 You Went Bust The Computer Wins")
else:
print("Ok well done lets see what the computer gets")
```

(Ignore this line please)
    computerscore=0
    while(computerscore)<21 and (computerscore)<(score):
    computer=random.randint(1,21)
    computerscore=(computerscore+computer)

```
time.sleep(3)
print(("The Computer Has Scored"),(computerscore))
if(computerscore)<=21 and (computerscore)>(score):

print("sorry the computer wins")
else:
print("You win well done")
break
```

I ran it in the CMD

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get "expected an indented block" when I try to run my Python script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257947/why-do-i-get-expected-an-indented-block-when-i-try-to-run-my-python-script)

Comment: No looked at that but it doesnt help for me

Comment: you need to indent your code properly. please read the docs

Comment: I know i'm new to coding but can you please help me answer this question?

Comment: indent your code. put 4 spaces before lines that need it

Comment: You have to indent properly - otherwise it's a syntax error. First read the tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ then ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to indent the blocks after your conditions lines, that's how python understands if you're still in the condition or not.

```
if a>b:
    print b
    print "I'm still in the case a>b"
else:
    print a
```

Use tab or 4 spaces to indent.

Comment: Its now saying break outside the loop?